# cannot find file on home directory after successfully uploading via gcloud compute scp

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I tried to upload a file called kaldi.sh to google cloud virtual machine.

So I tried `gcloud compute scp kaldi.sh vandys-0:~/experiment` as guided here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/. To be more specific:
`kaldi.sh` is the file I'd like to upload, `vandys-0` is my instance name, and `experiment` is the directory I would like to upload into.

The code runs well but when I activated the google cloud vm shell and entered into directory with path `~/experiemnt` (the same as `/home/[username]/experiment` I believe? ).  I found nothing from `ls`in the experiment directory.

I tried to use `gcloud compute scp kaldi.sh [username]@vandys-0:~/experiment` in the command instead. But it failed with error :

> [username]@35.196.87.176: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> lost connection

Any idea could help.

Comment: File you are copying is under the `user` you are copying it to. In this case it is `vandys-0`. First switch to `vandys-0` user and then do a `ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VM instance of a compute engine is distinct from the virtual machine used to run the cloud VM shell.   When you launch the cloud VM shell, that spawns its own (unique) instance of a virtual machine.  The purpose of the shell is simply to provide an environment in which you can run gcloud (or similar) admin commands.  What I think has happened is that you uploaded your file to your real compute engine instance and then opened up the cloud shell which would result in a separated (unrelated) instance being spawned for you.  These won't share file system data and hence it appeared that your file was missing.

To access the VM Instance to which the files were copied we can use the SSH window from the console browser.  The SSH window can be opened from the GCP console on the VM Instances page.

Comment: Hi @Kolban, I understand now. But the problem is, how can i used the uploading local file if I cannot find it via the shell?

Comment: Howdy, we are now into a new puzzle.   Let us assume you have created a cloud storage bucket called MYBUCKET and that you have a source file on your disk called myshell.sh.  If you want this copied to your Cloud Shell, then you would copy the shell script file to the bucket and then in the cloud shell, copy the source from the bucket.  


`$ gsutil cp myshell.sh gs://MYBUCKET`

and on VM shell:

`$ gsutil cp gs:://MYBUCKET/myshell.sh .`

Comment: Do you mean we have to use bucket to transfer? Then I am confused, what is the use of gcloud compute scp do if it cannot upload file to shell?

Comment: Within GCP, you can create as many VM instances as you like ... each one of those is created through "Compute Engine".    When you use `gcloud compute scp` you are naming one of the VM instances that you have previously created.    When you use the console cloud shell, that creates one additional VM that is used exclusively for quick entry of commands that are *outside* of any particular instance of a VM.

Comment: Thanks @Kolban. I totally understand that the shell creates another vm. But as you said the gcloud compute scp did send something to my target instances. I just want to know how to access those files (uploaded to my created instances)?

Comment: Let us imagine you create a VM instance called XYZ ... and then you uploaded a file to XYZ using gcloud command.   You should now find that if you login to the XYZ VM instance using SSH (see the VM Instances on the console web page) you will find the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181226/discussion-between-exteralvictor-and-kolban).